# How do I eliminate latches in FSM Verilog implementation?

Tags: verilog, latch, state-machines

I'm trying to create an FSM that left shifts a register until the MSB is 1 while counting the number of shifts completed. However, I have an issue with latches because I don't re-assign each register on a state change; namely, the shift and ctr registers (see the "if (shift[3])" statements). To get rid of the latches, I know that I need to assign these registers, but I don't want their values to change at the end--I want them to remain constant.

How do I achieve this?

```
`define RST 2'b00
`define LSH1 2'b01
`define LSH2 2'b10
`define DONE 2'b11

module leftshift(clk, rst, x, shift);
    input [3:0] x;
    input clk, rst;
    output [3:0] shift;

    reg [1:0] state, nextstate;

    reg [3:0] shift; // reg holding shifted bits
    reg [2:0] ctr; // ctr keeps track of how many shifts until completion

    always @ (posedge clk)
        if (rst) state <= `RST;
        else state <= nextstate;

    always @ (state, x, shift[3])
        case (state)
            `RST: begin
                shift <= x;
                ctr <= 0;
                nextstate <= `LSH1;
            end
            `LSH1: begin
                if (shift[3]) begin
                    //shift <= //don't change;
                    //ctr <= //don't change;
                    nextstate <= `DONE;
                end
                else begin
                    shift <= {shift[2:0], 1'b0};
                    ctr <= ctr+1;
                    nextstate <= `LSH2;
                end
            end
            `LSH2: begin
                if (shift[3]) begin
                    //ctr <= //don't change
                    //shift <= //don't change
                    nextstate <= `DONE;
                end
                else begin
                    shift <= {shift[2:0], 1'b0};
                    ctr <= ctr+1;
                    nextstate <= `LSH1;
                end
            end
            `DONE: begin
                //shift <= //don't change;
                //ctr <= //don't change;
                nextstate <= `DONE;
            end
        endcase
endmodule
```

Comment: @ThePhoton yeah I'm getting latch warnings from Xilinx ISE 14.7 and I'm about to tear by hair out I just want these errors to go away and nothing I've tried is fixing it. edit: ctr <= ctr didn't fix the warning, btw

Comment: @ThePhoton That exactly creates a latch in a combinational `always` block.

Comment: @ahmedus please help I see from your profile that you're a hardware guy

Comment: @ahmedus, oops. Didn't look at the sensitivity list.

Answer (score 4):

What I see is the coding style where you have a registered and a combinatorial section. It **is** a good coding style but it also only works if you are 100% consistent in your code:
Everything you clock (state, counter, shift) must be in the clock section. and you must only use non-blocking "<=" assignments.
All combinatorial code must be fully! encoded and you must only use blocking "=" assignments.
Start by adding a next_shift and next_cnt and in the clocking section use

```
always @ (posedge clk)
   if (rst) 
   begin
      state <= `RST_STATE;
      shift <= `RST_SHIFT;
      cnt   <= `RST_CNT;
   end
   else
   begin
      state <= next_state;
      shift <= next_shift;
      cnt   <= next_cnt;
   end
 end
```

I am not going to re-code your whole combinatorial section (sorry) but there you use:

```
always @ ( * ) // easiest!
begin
    case (state)
        `RST_STATE: begin
            next_shift = x;
            next_ctr   = 0;
            next_state = `DONE;
        end
        `LSH1: begin
             if (shift[3]) begin
               next_shift = shift; // no change
               next_ctr   = cntr;  // no change
               next_state = `DONE; // 
             end
             else begin 
               next_shift = {shift[2:0], 1'b0};
               next_ctr   = cntr+1;  
               next_state = `LSH2;
             end
  etc...

end
```

As I said it **is** a good coding style because it can handle some nasty cases better but the other coding style (I just saw another answer appear) is much easier.

Disclaimer: code not compiled there may be typos in there

Comment: I prefer the 2-always block largely because of [this paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003SJ_SystemVerilogFSM.pdf) which compares coding styles in terms of lines of code, synthesis timing, area synthesis area. 2-always blocks (w/ output encoded) wins most scenarios. No coding style is perfect for all situations (there wouldn't be a debate if there was), so it is go to be flexible if it is necessary to switch.

Comment: I have dropped processor cores from a big processor core supplier into silicon chips. I have seen their code and almost everywhere they follow that coding stile. I suspect it is a mandatory style. If a company of 3000 engineers with many years of experience follows it it can't be that bad.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting sequential and combinational parts is not efficient for your design. In addition, the combinational `always` block has non-blocking assignments (`<=`), which may cause unexpected synthesis results.

A single sequential `always` block should solve the problem.

```
always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) begin
        state <= `RST;
        shift <= 0;
        ctr <= 0;
    end else begin
        case (state)
            `RST: begin
                shift <= x;
                ctr <= 0;
                state <= `LSH1;
            end
            `LSH1: begin
                if (shift[3]) begin
                    //shift <= //don't change;
                    //ctr <= //don't change;
                    state <= `DONE;
                end
                else begin
                    shift <= {shift[2:0], 1'b0};
                    ctr <= ctr+1;
                    state <= `LSH2;
                end
            end
            `LSH2: begin
                if (shift[3]) begin
                    //ctr <= //don't change
                    //shift <= //don't change
                    state <= `DONE;
                end
                else begin
                    shift <= {shift[2:0], 1'b0};
                    ctr <= ctr+1;
                    state <= `LSH1;
                end
            end
            `DONE: begin
                //shift <= //don't change;
                //ctr <= //don't change;
                state <= `DONE;
            end
        endcase
    end
end
```

Both `ctr` and `shift` are flip-flop here. If there is no assignment in a case, they will preserve their values. The assignment `ctr <= ctr` also does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since code specific answers have already been given correctly by others. I just have a general answer to this question.

To avoid latches in a HDL design , two major points you have to keep in mind.

1)  Make sure that you cover all possible conditions in - case and if constructs, even though you feel that its not gonna appear in your design or you think is irrelavant. Because synthesizer will always "think" that such a condition will appear in your design and infer a latch for such conditions.

2) Once you did it the above thing correctly, the next step is to make sure that all the output/internal signals of your design get SOME value in every execution cycle, whatever the conditions are. Otherwise synthesizer will again infer latches to hold the previous values of uncovered signals.